# React Navigation - Setting params without navigating to the scene

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to add a 'reload' button to my header, which I'm doing by calling setParams. Problem is that this causes the TabNavigator to navigate to the tab at launch

```
 export default class FeedScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const { params } = navigation.state;
        if (params) {
            return {
                headerRight: <Icon.Button 
                    color="black" 
                    backgroundColor="transparent" 
                    underlayColor="transparent"
                    name="reload" 
                    onPress={ params.reload }
                />
            };
        }
    }

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        // We want to set attach a reload function to the navigation
        this.props.navigation.setParams({
            reload: this._reloadFeed.bind(this)
        });
    }
```

So is there a way setParams can not navigate to this scene, or is there a way to assign the function to this icon without calling setParams?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting onPress={ params.reload } to onPress={() => params.reload()}?

```
 export default class FeedScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const { params } = navigation.state;
        if (params) {
            return {
                headerRight: <Icon.Button 
                    color="black" 
                    backgroundColor="transparent" 
                    underlayColor="transparent"
                    name="reload" 
                    onPress={ () => params.reload() }  < -----
                />
            };
        }
    }

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        // We want to set attach a reload function to the navigation
        this.props.navigation.setParams({
            reload: this._reloadFeed.bind(this)
        });
    }
```

Comment: Didn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [Navigation Actions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#SetParams), specifically Navigation Action that is called "setParams" (do not confuse with `navigation.setParams()`), which you dispatch this way: `navigation.dispatch(myCreatedSetParamsAction)`

Comment: Unfortunately this still causes a navigation to the scene

Comment: @user1537360 maybe you do not need to .bind your _reloadFeed function. And also, maybe, you should set initialRouteParams in the navigatorConfig instead of setParams in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by calling a static function from the header, and just updating that static function to my reload function in the componentDidMount. It's hacky but works.

Function outside my component:

```
let _reloadFunction = () => {
    // This exists because react navigation is a mess
}
```

Navigation options

```
    static navigationOptions = {
        headerRight: <Icon.Button 
                        color="black" 
                        backgroundColor="transparent" 
                        underlayColor="transparent"
                        name="reload" 
                        onPress={() => { _reloadFunction() }}
                    />
    }
```

In the component:

```
        // Gonna update that reloadFunction so the header works
        _reloadFunction = this._reloadFeed.bind(this);
```